# How can I make Firebase analytics COPPA compliant using Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

How do I make Firebase Analytics COPPA compliant for Unity plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is not COPPA compliant as of today.

You can send a feature request to Firebase Support with details [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: How about now in 2019?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Support:

> The collection of analytics about children is not what's disallowed by COPPA, but rather the targeting of children based on analytics. If children are targeted based on Ads, the developers need to make sure to set up their ad-targeting appropriately. AdMob has a flag for this, for example. The developer will be the one to control what they do with the analytics data they collect, and they need to make sure to comply with COPPA if their app is child-directed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answers above are outdated. You may now [configure Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/configure-data-collection?platform=ios) to disable all device identifiers and/or delay data collection until you received legal consent. This should allow you your app to maintain COPPA compliance.